# PHP Mysql LIMIT failing in query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get messages with a joined query with 3 tables
everything works fine as expected but when i am trying to limit the results the query is failing and not returning anything

**query**

```
    SELECT 
        P.patient_name, 
        DM.message, 
        DM.secsince, 
        DM.id, 
        DM.pid, 
        DM.did, 
        DM.mode, 
        DM.date, 
        DM.seen 
    FROM tbl_patient P, 
        tbl_doct D, 
        tbl_doct_messages DM 
    WHERE (DM.did = D.id AND DM.pid = P.id) 
        AND (DM.mode = 'in') 
        AND (D.id = '$id') 
    ORDER BY DM.secsince DESC;
```

This query works fine and gives me expected results

but when I use LIMIT it is failing and not returning anything for some reason

**query**

```
SELECT 
    P.patient_name, 
    DM.message, 
    DM.secsince, 
    DM.id, 
    DM.pid, 
    DM.did, 
    DM.mode, 
    DM.date, 
    DM.seen 
FROM tbl_patient P, 
    tbl_doct D, 
    tbl_doct_messages DM 
WHERE (DM.did = D.id AND DM.pid = P.id) 
    AND (DM.mode = 'in') 
    AND (D.id = '$id') 
ORDER BY 
   DM.secsince DESC; 
LIMIT=1;
```

**here is the whole php code**

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
if(mysqli_connect_error($con)) {
    echo "Failed To Connect";
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$qry = "SELECT P.patient_name, DM.message, DM.secsince, DM.id, DM.pid, DM.did, DM.mode, DM.date, DM.seen 
        FROM tbl_patient P, tbl_doct D, tbl_doct_messages DM 
        WHERE (DM.did = D.id AND DM.pid = P.id) AND (DM.mode = 'in') AND (D.id = '$id') 
        ORDER BY DM.secsince DESC 
        LIMIT=1;";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
$flag = array();
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))){
    array_push($flag, $row);
}
echo json_encode($flag); 
mysqli_close($con);     
?>
```

As you can see in this picture it gives me results without the **limit**
[image]

But no results so mysqli_fetch_array is failing when i add the **limit**

[image]

Why this happening ? i basically am out of ideas.

Comment: Try `LIMIT 1` not `LIMIT=1`

Comment: Also, indent your SQL code, it will be benefic for you.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Parameterize. Also use `join` and `on` syntax. Don't use the comma notation for `join`s with the `where` for the join criteria.

Comment: I would encourage you to cease using this syntax, which was effectively deprecated 20 years ago. Come. JOIN us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your query

from

```
SELECT 
    P.patient_name, 
    DM.message, 
    DM.secsince, 
    DM.id, DM.pid, 
    DM.did, DM.mode, 
    DM.date, DM.seen 
FROM 
    tbl_patient P, 
    tbl_doct D, 
    tbl_doct_messages DM 
WHERE 
    (DM.did = D.id AND DM.pid = P.id) AND 
    (DM.mode = 'in') AND (D.id = '$id') 
ORDER BY 
   DM.secsince DESC 
LIMIT=1
```

to remove the **=**

```
SELECT 
    P.patient_name, 
    DM.message, 
    DM.secsince, 
    DM.id, DM.pid, 
    DM.did, DM.mode, 
    DM.date, DM.seen 
FROM 
    tbl_patient P, 
    tbl_doct D, 
    tbl_doct_messages DM 
WHERE 
    (DM.did = D.id AND DM.pid = P.id) AND 
    (DM.mode = 'in') AND (D.id = '$id') 
ORDER BY 
   DM.secsince DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the right syntax is `LIMIT 1` and not `LIMIT = 1`